# How many queries per second can GAE support with 5 SNI certificate slots?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-apps, sni

You can now purchase SNI certificate slots on google apps for custom domains.

It costs $9 for 5 SNI, but I can't figure out how to do my capacity planning.

How many SNI slots do I need to buy? How many queries per second can 1 SNI slot handle? Does it matter how many simultaneous connections are open to my GAE app?

Answer (score 7):

I think you don't quite understand what a [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) slot is. SNI slots don't handle queries, they hold certificates. You need one for each certificate. It has nothing to do with the number of connections.

If you only want to serve one site with one certificate, you don't need SNI at all.

Comment: That last statement is not correct - you need either SNI or a dedicated SSL IP to serve with your own certificate on App Engine.

Comment: If you don't have a dedicated SSL IP, then you want to serve more than one site with more than one certificate, in which case you do need SNI.

Comment: Well, yes. Which is the case on App Engine, because you don't have dedicated IPs unless you pay for them. So you need SNI even if you only want to serve one site.

Comment: @NickJohnson I know it's late, but do any of you know why then Google sell 5 slots instead of 1 slot, if each application can use 1 slot. As you say, it's per site. Cause it's not per page, right?

Comment: @Sti The point of SNI is to select which certificate to send. So a single slot wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Is there a point in having more than one certificate for a single website? I'm not sure I completely understand SNI/SSL. Is VIP-certificate only one certificate?

Comment: @Sti The point would be that you have more than one web site.